# How to create an instance of java.io.File from a byte[] without saving the file to the disk

Tags: java, arrays, file, memory

I must use an existing method: `method.invoke(myClassLoader, myFile.toURI().toURL());` where `myFile` is an instance of `File` and I need to create it from a `byte[]` without saving the file on the disk, is this possible?

This is what I tried but it creates a file on the disk and writes it:

```
    byte[] bytes = ...;
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    fos.write(bytes);
    method.invoke(myClassLoader, tempFile.toURI().toURL());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of the invoked method is `URL`. You can use Jimfs (An in-memory file system for Java 7+) to create a file emulation in memory and get its URL (`path.toUri().toURL()`).